# How do I get the first line of text from a DataGridView column after word-wrap?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and it contains a column with wordwrap. So I want to get the first line of the column after wrapping. How do I achieve it?

For example:

Main line:

```
This is a test message to show what I really need to achieve from the DataGridView cell.
```

Wrapped text:

```
This is a test message
to show what I really
need to achieve from
the DataGridView cell.
```

Desired output:

```
This is a test message.
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the actual requirements, why you want to do it?

Comment: Basically when I have data in the cell of `DataGridView`, the value is a full sentence and I have implemented the find and replace function in it. So, when I am finding a value, it is working perfectly, but at the time of highlighting it, it is treating it as one line, so the highlight is not visible. But, if I manually resize the panel to bring the column value in one line, it highlights else no. Please help.